# How do i set a default property for this variable?

Tags: vb.net

The Loc variable is underlined and says it cannot be indexed because it has no default property. Can I set a default property or is there something else I can and should do?

```
    Private Sub tmrLeft_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles tmrLeft.Tick
    Dim MoveSpeed As Integer = 10
    Dim Loc As Point
    If Not picPlayer.Location.X - MoveSpeed < 0 Then
        Loc = New Point(picPlayer.Location.X - MoveSpeed, picPlayer.Location.Y)
        picPlayer.Location = Loc()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses?

Comment: It says System.Drawing.Point cannot be indexed.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you

Comment: I mean, change it from `picPlayer.Location = Loc()` to `picPlayer.Location = Loc`

Comment: It worked. I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  I'll write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have some unnecessary parentheses.  You need to change this line:

```
picPlayer.Location = Loc()
```

to this:

```
picPlayer.Location = Loc
```

Parentheses can be a little confusing in VB, since they can be used for either a method invocation or a list item index.  In this context, `Loc` is a variable, not a method, so when you put the parentheses after it, the compiler assumes that you must be attempting to access a particular item of a list by index.  But, since `Loc` is not an array, and it's not a list with a default index-accessible property (like `List.Item`, where it's the default indexer, so `myList.Item(3)` means the same thing as `myList(3)`).  So, it gives an error saying that `Loc` can't be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

In programming (VBA in this case), parentheses are included when you reference a method:

> This is variable
>
> `Dim Loc As Point`
>
> `Dim NewPoint = Loc`
>
> This is a method
>
> ```
>  'Function to Add Two Numbers and Then Subtract a Third Number
>      Function SumMinus(dNum1 As Double, dNum2 As Double, dNum3 As Double) As Double
>      SumMinus = dNum1 + dNum2 - dNum3
>      End Function
> ```
>
> `Dim Result As Double`
>
> `Result = SumMinus(..., ..., ...);`
>
> As you see, the parentheses give it a different meaning.
>
> `variable`
>
> `method()`

---

```
Private Sub tmrLeft_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles tmrLeft.Tick
        Dim MoveSpeed As Integer = 10
        Dim Loc As Point
        If Not picPlayer.Location.X - MoveSpeed < 0 Then
            Loc = New Point(picPlayer.Location.X - MoveSpeed, picPlayer.Location.Y)
            picPlayer.Location = Loc // Without parenthesis
        End If
    End Sub
```